# How to properly get a List<Object> with ManyToMany relationship with PostMapping?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Started learning the spring framework (spring boot) and ran into a problem.
Trying to assign selected authors to perform newly created task.
How to properly get a `List<Object>` with `@ManyToMany` relationship with PostMapping?
Here is my simple code:

Task entity:

```
@Entity @Data
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long taskId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "taskList")
    private List<User> userList;
}
```

User entity:

```
@Entity @Data
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long user_id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="task_authors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="taskId")
    )
    private List<Task> taskList;
}
```

TaskController:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public String addTask(
        @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails currentUser,
        @RequestParam("WebsiteId") Website website,
        @ModelAttribute Task task,
        @RequestParam("taskAuthors") List<User> taskAuthors
) {
    User owner = (User) userService.findUserByEmail(currentUser.getUsername());
    task.setOwnerId(owner.getUser_id());

    task.setUserList(taskAuthors);

    taskService.addTask(task);
    return "redirect:/tasks";
}
```

Sample table:

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | task_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       5 |
|       2 |       5 |
|       3 |       5 |
+---------+---------+
```

When submitting the form, the task is created, but the table above is not filled.

Screenshot from browsers "Network" tab:
[image]

This line of code from GetMapping (task submission form)

```
@GetMapping("/add")
public String addTaskForm(
        Model model,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails currentUser
) {

    User user = (User) userService.findUserByEmail(currentUser.getUsername());
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("authors",userService.getAllUsersAuthors(user.getUser_id()));

    return "backend/add-task";
}
```

Where am I wrong? Do I need to create a wrapper? Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

- configure `cascadeType` for User

  ```
  public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long user_id;

    //look here bro
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "task_authors",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "taskId")
    )

    private List<Task> taskList;
  }
  ```
- exchange the `mappedBy` and `@JoinTable`

Comment: Thank you so much, bro! You saved my life)) Worked the 2nd variant with exchanging the mappedBy & @JoinTable.

Answer (score 1):

the way you have defined the relations, the User is the owner of relation and Task is the inverse side so adding users to task will not create any new rows in database. If you move the "mappedBy" to User and JoinTable to Task, then Task becomes the owner of relation and it will do what you want.